# how to transfer a binary file through serial port in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Hi i have to read a binary file from the disk and i have to transfer the file over serial port, i am using mscomm in vc++ 6.0 .

how to transfer a binary file through serial port.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comprehensive library on CodeProject - ['Serial library for C++'](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial.aspx).

Here is a sample use case from that.

```
CSerial serial;

// Attempt to open the serial port (COM1)
serial.Open(_T("COM1"));

// Setup the serial port (9600,N81) using hardware handshaking
serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud9600,CSerial::EData8,CSerial::EParNone,CSerial::EStop1);
serial.SetupHandshaking(CSerial::EHandshakeHardware);

// The serial port is now ready and we can send/receive data. If
// the following call blocks, then the other side doesn't support
// hardware handshaking.
serial.Write("Hello world");

// Close the port again
serial.Close();
```

It includes both asynchronous and synchronous implementations.